Phase Space Integral For Compton Scattering COM Frame
I have a question about how to compute the phase space integral for Compton scattering in the COM frame. I was following Peskin and Schroeder Introduction to Quantum Field Theory. They have the following lines on page 163:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int d \Pi_2 & =\int \frac{d^3 k^{\prime}}{(2 \pi)^3} \frac{1}{2 \omega^{\prime}} \frac{d^3 p^{\prime}}{(2 \pi)^3} \frac{1}{2 E^{\prime}}(2 \pi)^4 \delta^{(4)}\left(k^{\prime}+p^{\prime}-k-p\right) \\
& =\int \frac{\left(\omega^{\prime}\right)^2 d \omega^{\prime} d \Omega}{(2 \pi)^3} \frac{1}{4 \omega^{\prime} E^{\prime}} \\
& \times 2 \pi \delta\left(\omega^{\prime}+\sqrt{m^2+\omega^2+\left(\omega^{\prime}\right)^2-2 \omega \omega^{\prime} \cos \theta}-\omega-m\right) \\
& =\int \frac{d \cos \theta}{2 \pi} \frac{\omega^{\prime}}{4 E^{\prime}} \frac{1}{\left|1+\frac{\omega^{\prime}-\omega \cos \theta}{E^{\prime}}\right|}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Here $k^{\prime}$ is the outgoing photon, and $p^{\prime}$ is the outgoing electron. I understand how to get from the second expression to the third from The phase space integral for Compton scattering. My question is how we get from the first line to the second? I see we take spherical coordinates for $d^3k^{\prime} \rightarrow \omega_2d\omega_2 d\Omega$ then use $d\Omega \rightarrow 2\pi d\cos(\theta)$, but what happened to the$\frac{d^3p^{'}}{(2\pi)^3}$? Does it have to do with assuming $p^{'} = k-k^{'}+p$ from momentum conservation and some sort of spherical integral? Could someone show me explicitly?


As explicitly stated on p. 162 of Peskin-Schroeder, they are computing the Compton scattering cross section in the laboratory frame (where $\vec{p}=0$ and $E=m$) and not in the center of mass (COM) frame.

The second line of their formula is simply obtained by performing the  integration over $\vec{p}^\prime$ taking advantage of the three-dimensional delta function $\delta^{(3)}(\vec{p}^\prime+\vec{k}^\prime-\vec{p}-\vec{k})=\delta^{(3)}(\vec{p}^\prime+\vec{k}^\prime-\vec{k})$ (remember $\vec{p}=0$ in the lab frame). As a consequence, $$\begin{align}E^\prime &=\sqrt{\vec{p}^{\prime \, 2}+m^2} \\[5pt] &=\sqrt{\left(\vec{k}-\vec{k}^\prime\right)^2+m^2} \\[5pt] &=\sqrt{\omega^2+\omega^{\prime \, 2}-2 \vec{k} \cdot \vec{k}^\prime+m^2}\\[5pt] &=\sqrt{\omega^2+\omega^{\prime \, 2}-2\omega \omega^\prime\cos \theta+m^2} \end{align}$$ and the remaining one-dimensional delta function takes the form $$\delta(\omega^\prime+E^\prime-\omega-E)=\delta(\omega^\prime+\sqrt{\omega^2+\omega^{\prime \, 2}-2 \omega \omega^\prime \cos \theta +m^2}-\omega -m).$$

It is in fact easier to compute the phase-space integral by employing the well-known formula $$\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\vec{p}^{\prime \, 2}+m^2}}=\int \! dp^{\prime \, 0}\, \theta(p^{\prime \, 0} )\,\delta(p^{\prime \, 2}-m^2),$$ giving the frame-independent expression $$\int \! d\Pi_2= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int \frac{d^3 k^\prime}{2\omega^\prime}\, \theta(\omega+E-\omega^\prime)\, \delta\left((k+p-k^\prime)^2-m^2\right).$$ Specializing to the lab frame and switching to spherical coordinates, the final result (cf. eqs. (5.89) and (5.90) on p.163 of Peskin-Schroeder) $$\int \! d\Pi_2= \frac{1}{8\pi} \int \! d\cos \theta \, \,\frac{\omega^{\,\prime \, 2}}{m \omega}, \qquad  \omega^\prime= \frac{\omega}{^1+\frac{\omega}{m}(1-\cos \theta)}$$ is obtained after a few lines.


